# Al consultar la función me da el resultado en "null" y necesito que me arroje un valor. (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, funciones, sql

Estoy creando la función para obtener el costo total de una venta a partir de su ID, la base de datos es Northwind. El código en el que trabajo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando realizo la consulta siguiente:

```
SELECT dbo.CostOrden (10248);
```

Me arroja el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me arroja el resultado correspondiente que debería ser de **440.** ¿Qué le hace falta a mi código para que me arroje el resultado correspondiente?

Comment: Sugerencia: Para que otros la tengan más fácil replicando tu problema, procura compartir tu código como texto. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía tu función de este modo

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION totalPrecios (ventaID INTEGER)
RETURNS INT(5)
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
FROM orderdetails
WHERE OrderID = ventaID);

END
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Importante declara un `DELIMITER $$` al inicio de tu función
- Le paso un argumento a la función llamado `ventaID` de tipo `INTEGER`
- Le indico que me retornará un entero con una longitud de 5
- Envuelvo todo mi `SELECT` dentro de la sentencia `RETURN`
- Hago por dentro uso de la función de agregación `SUM()` para envolver la multiplicación
- En el `WHERE` hago la igualación de la columna `orderID` que es parte de la tabla con el valor que tu usuario va a ingresar a la función por medio de la variable `ventaID` que es el valor que declaramos al inicio
- Omití todas las demás variables, puesto que a como redactas tu intención es solo pasar el `ID` de la venta para identificar donde hacer la multiplicación, por lo que veo innecesarias todas las demás
- Si te fijas también añadí en la declaración de la función que usuario y en que ambiente la definió con ayuda de `DEFINER=root@localhost`

**INVOCANDO A LA FUNCIÓN**

Para invocar a la función ejecuto lo siguiente

```
SELECT totalPrecios(10248);
```

Lo cual me retorna como resultado

```
totalPrecios(10248)
-------------------
440
```

Si durante la creación de la función te aparece un error relacionado a

> DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary
>   logging is enabled

Ejecuta en consola el siguiente comando

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

El posible error, **que aclaro es solo si te aparece** lo que hace es verificar sobre funciones no deterministicas que modifican datos, como la de actualizar, insertar o eliminar; al tu ejecutar el último comando que te muestro estableces que se permita la ejecución de las mismas

Ya con el procedimiento anterior te debe estar mostrando el resultado como yo te lo enseño

> (No borraré la respuesta, pero no leí bien y acabo de ver que estas
>   trabajando con SQL Server y mi aporte es para MySQL/MariDB) aún así
>   espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

debes asignar la variable @Costo la suma de UnitPrice * Quantity y luego castear a int y retornarlo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CostOrden(@OrderID INT) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Costo int=0;

    SELECT @Costo=CAST( SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity ) AS INT )
    FROM OrderDetails
    WHERE OrderID = @OrderID;

    RETURN @Costo;
END
```